# OpenLDAP memberof Overlay not showing

Tags: ldap, openldap, memberof

The memberOf attribute is not showing in ldap simple search if I do the following then memberOf attribute is hidden.

**ldapsearch -Y external -H ldapi:/// -b dc=example,dc=com**

```
# udraz, Users, example.com
dn: uid=udraz,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
uid: udraz
sn: Draz
givenName: Umar
mail: udraz@example.com
cn: Umar Draz
displayName: Umar Draz
uidNumber: 5000
gidNumber: 5000
gecos: Umar Draz
loginShell: /bin/bash
homeDirectory: /home/udraz
```

But if I do the following then memberOf attribute appear

**ldapsearch -Y external -H ldapi:/// -b dc=example,dc=com memberOf**

```
# udraz, Users, example.com
dn: uid=udraz,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
memberOf: cn=developers,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
```

Would you please help me how to solve this

Comment: From the [documentation](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html): 'Note that the `memberOf` attribute is an operational attribute, so it must be requested explicitly.'.

Comment: But I have jumpcloud ldap services, and there it is working without any explicitly request. The following command also have the memberOf attribute as well
`ldapsearch -H ldaps://ldap.jumpcloud.com -x -b "ou=Users,o=adf241e11d4dasf049afb,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com" -D 'uid=udraz,ou=Users,o=adf241e11d4dasf049afb,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com' -W`

Comment: Is that server using OpenLDAP?

Comment: Yes, they might had customized their ldap server

Comment: Clearly it isn't OpenLDAP, because it doesn't behave as described in the OpenLDAP documentationm I cited. This one is and it does. So if you want the same code to work for both you have to specifically request `memberOf`, or request all operational attributes with `+`.